# Matlab Carving Seam function calling

Tags: matlab, function

I want to do a seam carving in an image using Matlab.

If i do it using only scripts and not by calling the function,it works.The problem comes when i make the script as a function and try to call it

The code i use

**Final Script:** Its the script i use to call the function over and over so i get the result

```
clear all;
close all;

%Image = 'mall.jpg';

Image_Array = imread('mall.jpg');

%We keep the dimension of the image array
[Row_Count,Column_Count,Colour] = size(Image_Array);

Image = double(Image_Array)/255;
Image = rgb2gray(Image);

for i = 1 : 10
[Image_Array,Row_Count,Column_Count]=Vertical_Seam(Image_Array,Row_Count,Column_Count);
imshow(Image_Array);
end
```

**Vertical Seam:** its the script i use to do the work of seaming.This is the file i would like to make it a function and call it in the Finalscript but i dont know how(You will notice that i tried to make a fucntion but as it didnt work i put it inside % )

```
%function [Final_Image,Row_Count,Column_Count] = Vertical_Seam(Image_Array,Row_Count,Column_Count)

Image_Array = imread('mall.jpg');

%We keep the dimension of the image array
[Row_Count,Column_Count,Colour] = size(Image_Array);

Image = double(Image_Array)/255;
Image = rgb2gray(Image);

for repeat = 1 : 10

%Calculate the energy
[E_x,E_y] = gradient(Image);
Energy = abs(E_x) + abs(E_y);

%We run the image and keep the minimum sum-energy in Image_Array
Cumulative_Energy = zeros(Row_Count,Column_Count);

% i represent rows 
% j represent columns
for i = 1 : Row_Count
    for j = 1 : Column_Count
        if i==1
            Cumulative_Energy(i,j) = Energy(i,j);
        elseif i>1
                if j==1
                   temp1 = [Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j+1)];
                   Cumulative_Energy(i,j) = Energy(i,j) + min(temp1);
                elseif j>1 && j<Column_Count
                   temp2 = [Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j-1),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j+1)];
                   Cumulative_Energy(i,j) = Energy(i,j) + min(temp2);   
                elseif j==Column_Count
                   temp3 = [Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j-1),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,j)];
                   Cumulative_Energy(i,j) = Energy(i,j) + min(temp3);
                end
        end
    end
end

%Find the minimum value from last column

temp_min = Cumulative_Energy(Row_Count,1);
point_min = 1;

for j = 2 : Column_Count
    if Cumulative_Energy(Row_Count,j)<temp_min
        temp_min = Cumulative_Energy(Row_Count,j);
        point_min = j;
    end
end

%Start from the minimum value from last column and backtrack to find the minimum seam

%We need an array to keep minimum energy in every row while
%backtracking
Keep_Seam = zeros(Row_Count,1);
Keep_Seam(Row_Count) = temp_min;

%We need also the point of the minimum energy (the number of column)
Keep_Point = zeros(Row_Count,1);
Keep_Point(Row_Count) = point_min;

%Paint the pixel
Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,Row_Count,point_min);


for i = Row_Count : -1 : 1
    if i==1
        if point_min==1
            Tmp1 = [Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min),Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min+1)];
            Keep_Seam(i) = min(Tmp1);

            if min(Tmp1)==Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min)
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min; 
            else
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min+1;
               point_min = point_min+1;
            end

            Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,i,point_min);

        elseif point_min==Column_Count
            Tmp2 = [Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min-1),Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min)];
            Keep_Seam(i) = min(Tmp2);

            if min(Tmp2)==Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min)
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min;
            else
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min-1;
               point_min = point_min-1;
           end

            Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,i,point_min);

        elseif point_min>1 && point_min<Column_Count
            Tmp3 = [Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min-1),Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min),Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min+1)];
            Keep_Seam(i) = min(Tmp3);

             if min(Tmp3)==Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min)
                Keep_Point(i) = point_min;
             elseif min(Tmp3)==Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min-1)
                Keep_Point(i) = point_min-1;
                point_min = point_min-1;
             elseif min(Tmp3)==Cumulative_Energy(i,point_min+1)
                Keep_Point(i) = point_min+1;
                point_min = point_min+1;
             end

            Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,i,point_min);
        end
   elseif i==Row_Count || i<Row_Count 
        if point_min==1
            Temp1 = [Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min+1)];
            Keep_Seam(i) = min(Temp1);

           if min(Temp1)== Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min)
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min;
           else
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min+1;
               point_min = point_min+1;
           end

           Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,i,point_min);

        elseif point_min==Column_Count
            Temp2 = [Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min-1),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min)];
            Keep_Seam(i) = min(Temp2);

            if min(Temp2)==Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min)
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min;
            else
               Keep_Point(i) = point_min-1;
               point_min = point_min-1;
            end

            Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,i,point_min);

        elseif point_min>1 && point_min<Column_Count
            Temp3 = [Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min-1),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min),Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min+1)];
            Keep_Seam(i) = min(Temp3);

            if min(Temp3)==Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min)
                 Keep_Point(i) = point_min;
             elseif min(Temp3)==Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min-1)
                 Keep_Point(i) = point_min-1;
                 point_min = point_min-1;
             elseif min(Temp3)==Cumulative_Energy(i-1,point_min+1)
                 Keep_Point(i) = point_min+1;
                 point_min = point_min+1;
            end

            Image_Array = Image_Colouring(Image_Array,i,point_min);
        end     
    end
end

imshow(Image_Array);

Image_Seam = zeros(Row_Count,Column_Count-1,Colour,'uint8');

for i = 1 : Row_Count
     Image_Seam(i,:,:)=Image_Array(i,[1:Keep_Point(i)-1,Keep_Point(i)+1:Column_Count],:);
end    
%imshow(Image_Seam);

Image_Array = Image_Seam;

end

% end
```

I would like to connect those two files so the Finalscript will call the Verticalseam as function and not as a script

Comment: this is a lot of uncommented code. What error you get? Try to break down your code a bit. And I don't really get, do you want to call the function directly from the editor? or do you want to use the script above and call the function from the script? Why do you have congruent code outside and inside the function?